# List in list with image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Hi I have problem with styling html lists with image.
I know about 2 way how replace default "image" (dot, rectangle etc..) with my image.

1) styling "ul" with "list-style-image"

```
ul{
padding-left: 26px;
list-style-image:url("../../img/ic-odrazka.png")
}
```

2) styling "li" with "background-image"

```
ul{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
li{
  padding-left: 26px;
  background-position: left 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../../img/ic-odrazka.png");
}
```

Problem is when I work with list in list then both solution not work.
=> Solution not work in code structure as:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>one1</li>
      <li>two2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>next</li>
</ul>
```

Is there some way how get it work?

[Jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/a2L7L48g/1/)

Comment: Works on FF 50.1.0 and on FF 51.0.1

Comment: On fist line in inner list I have 2 cube this is not so nice. I search for solution where I get only 1 cube as default function of lists.

Comment: @Harry I think when list is used inside list then we see list image 2 times. This might be the issue.

Comment: @SevereTorture You might need to take help from js that will detect presence of ul inside li and add class on it. From this class you can override styles of the list item that contains a child list.

Comment: @Muhammad Usman: I mean using JS isn't important and this is not so clear. I mean this here is some pure CSS solution..

Comment: @Harry: In Chrome on Windows I see 2 cube on line where start inner list.

Comment: @Harry list item #1 of the inner list has it's cube and the one of the outer list.

Comment: Oh yeah just the first one alone has @elementzero23. Thanks for pointing that out. But that's not a bug or something wrong. It is just how it is supposed to work. The outer one will have its own bullet and then each inner one would have theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants to do it in pure CSS then there are a couple of possible variants to do this. One requires `HTML` changes while other doesn't but it has its limitations:

**Method #01 (With HTML Changes):**

In this method, we will create an extra element inside `li` and apply styles to it instead of list items.

Consider the following modified `HTML`:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>one</span></li>
  <li><span>two</span></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>one</span></li>
      <li><span>two</span></li>
      <li><span>one1</span></li>
      <li><span>two2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>next</span></li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li > span {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 26px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-position: left 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://sablony.ekonstrukter.cz/sablony/162/ikona_nabidky.gif");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>one</span></li>
  <li><span>two</span></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>one</span></li>
      <li><span>two</span></li>
      <li><span>one1</span></li>
      <li><span>two2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>next</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Method #02 (Without HTML Changes):**

This method doesn't require any `HTML` changes in code. In this technique we will hide the excess list image with an overlay. Below are the steps:

1. Create an overlay with `:before` or `:after` pseudo element of nested list with the same or a slightly more `width` / `height` of bullet image.
2. Apply the same `background-color` on this overlay as on the nearest ancestor having `background`.
3. Place this overlay on exactly on top of the bullet of parent `li` which contains the nested list.

> **Note:** This will work only if the nearest ancestor has solid `background-color` (It won't work in case of gradient or background image).

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}
ul{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  padding-left: 26px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-position: left 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://sablony.ekonstrukter.cz/sablony/162/ikona_nabidky.gif");
}

li ul:before {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: -28px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>one1</li>
      <li>two2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>next</li>
</ul>
```

**Method #03 (With JavaScript / jQuery):**

In this method we will select list items having nested lists with some library like jQuery etc. Below is the necessary code required to make it work:

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('ul li:has("ul")').addClass('has-list');
```

**CSS:**

```
li.has-list {
  background: none;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul li:has("ul")').addClass('has-list');
});
```

```css
ul{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
li{
  padding-left: 26px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-position: left 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://sablony.ekonstrukter.cz/sablony/162/ikona_nabidky.gif");
}
li.has-list {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>one1</li>
      <li>two2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>next</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This sounds good, but there is one problem. I can´t add spans into lists without javascript because this situation can create user in administration. If this be in static web then no problem and its work.

Comment: @SevereTorture As I have already mentioned that you might need to take help from JS and that would be a better approach in this case where `HTML` can't be modified.

Comment: Method #03 sounds good. Very short jQuery and work for a lot of list in lists. I accept this as answer. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id ("inner" for example) to the `<li>` containing another `<ul>` and then do

```
#inner {
  list-style: none;
  background-image: none;
}
```

in CSS. Or do this with a class, if you have several `<li>` that contain `<ul>`.

Or dynamically with jQuery:

```
$("li").each(function () {
  if ( $(this).children("ul").length ) {
    $(this).css("background-image", "none");
  }
});
```

Comment: This is hard coded and not a good solution. OP's code can have any number of list items having child lists. So he should use `id` for each list item and style accordinlgy?